# Android Studio - Cannot resolve com.google.firebase.analytics

Tags: android-studio, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using Android Studio and (tried) to add firebase.analytics via the menu (tools->firebase). I added the analytics function but

```
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;
```

results in an error since "analytics" cannot be resolved.

What is missing? 
Many thanks!

Comment: Please post your error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you've compiled all needed firebase libraries for analytics in your gradle app file.

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
}
```

Check this for more information : https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/

Comment: It seems that with the new documentation, you don't need to add firebase-core anymore, just adding com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics will do